# How to create checkbox and input text fields in docx document?

Tags: java, apache-poi, apache-poi-4

I'm a new in apache poi could anyone help me with creating checkboxes and fillable fields(plain text, rich text) in docx document? I saw xml representation of docx and I think that is element describe checkbox

```
<w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin">
          <w:ffData>
            <w:name w:val="Check59"/>
            <w:enabled/>
            <w:calcOnExit w:val="0"/>
            <w:checkBox>
              <w:sizeAuto/>
              <w:default w:val="0"/>
            </w:checkBox>
          </w:ffData>
        </w:fldChar>
      </w:r>
      <w:bookmarkStart w:id="6" w:name="Check59"/>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:sz w:val="20"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:instrText xml:space="preserve">FORMCHECKBOX</w:instrText>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:sz w:val="20"/>
        </w:rPr>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:sz w:val="20"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end"/>
      </w:r>
```

and that xml elements describe input text:

```
<w:r>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:sz w:val="20"/>
          <w:u w:val="single"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin">
          <w:ffData>
            <w:name w:val="Text1"/>
            <w:enabled/>
            <w:calcOnExit w:val="0"/>
            <w:textInput/>
          </w:ffData>
        </w:fldChar>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:sz w:val="20"/>
          <w:u w:val="single"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:instrText xml:space="preserve">FORMTEXT</w:instrText>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:sz w:val="20"/>
          <w:u w:val="single"/>
        </w:rPr>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:sz w:val="20"/>
          <w:u w:val="single"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate"/>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:noProof/>
          <w:sz w:val="20"/>
          <w:u w:val="single"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t> </w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:noProof/>
          <w:sz w:val="20"/>
          <w:u w:val="single"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t> </w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:noProof/>
          <w:sz w:val="20"/>
          <w:u w:val="single"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t> </w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:noProof/>
          <w:sz w:val="20"/>
          <w:u w:val="single"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t> </w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:noProof/>
          <w:sz w:val="20"/>
          <w:u w:val="single"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t> </w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:sz w:val="20"/>
          <w:u w:val="single"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end"/>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:sz w:val="20"/>
          <w:u w:val="single"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:tab/>
      </w:r>
      <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
          <w:sz w:val="20"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t xml:space="preserve">,“Seller” whether one or more, and</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
```

but how that is get from apache poi or create the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as you know the `XML` needed in the `Office Open XML` `Word` document, you also can creating it using `apache poi`. `Apache poi` bases on the `ooxml-schemas` which are `Java` classes created from the `XML` schema definitions of `Office Open XML`. That's why there are classes for each of the `XML` elements described in those schema definitions.

Unfortunately there is not any documentation about the ooxml schemas public available. So we need downloading the sources of [ooxml-schemas](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/poi/ooxml-schemas/1.4/) and then doing `javadoc` form those to get a API documentation which describes the classes and methods.

There we then find `org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.*` classes  which are the classes for word processing part of  `Office Open XML`.

Note `ooxml-schemas` version `1.4` is for usage together with `apache poi 4.0.0` or newer. For older versions  `ooxml-schemas` version `1.3` is needed.

For inserting form fields in `Word` we need `Interface CTFldChar`, `Interface STFldCharType` and `Interface CTString`.

Example code:

```
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.*;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

/*
needs the full ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar as mentioned in https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025
*/

public class WordInsertFormFields {

 static void insertFormField(XWPFParagraph paragraph, String type, CTString[] options) {
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.getCTR().addNewFldChar().setFldCharType(STFldCharType.BEGIN);
  if ("FORMTEXT".equals(type)) {
   run.getCTR().getFldCharArray(0).addNewFfData().addNewTextInput();
  } else if ("FORMDROPDOWN".equals(type)) {
   run.getCTR().getFldCharArray(0).addNewFfData().addNewDdList().setListEntryArray(options);
  } else if ("FORMCHECKBOX".equals(type)) {
   run.getCTR().getFldCharArray(0).addNewFfData().addNewCheckBox();
  }
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.getCTR().addNewInstrText().setStringValue(type);
  if ("FORMTEXT".equals(type)) {
   run = paragraph.createRun();
   run.getCTR().addNewFldChar().setFldCharType(STFldCharType.SEPARATE);
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    run = paragraph.createRun();
    //run.setText(" "); // Unicode Character 'EN SPACE' (U+2002)
    run.setText("\u2002");
   }
  }
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.getCTR().addNewFldChar().setFldCharType(STFldCharType.END);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("Input Name: ");
  insertFormField(paragraph, "FORMTEXT", null);

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("Choose gender: ");
  CTString male = CTString.Factory.newInstance(); male.setVal("male");
  CTString female = CTString.Factory.newInstance(); female.setVal("female");
  insertFormField(paragraph, "FORMDROPDOWN", new CTString[]{male, female});

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText("Will you answer mails?: ");
  insertFormField(paragraph, "FORMCHECKBOX", null);

  document.enforceFillingFormsProtection();

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("WordInsertFormFields.docx"));
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: How can I set the checkbox as **checked** programmatically with apache poi?

Comment: @demir5334: When? Directly while creating? Then: `CTFFCheckBox checkbox = run.getCTR().getFldCharArray(0).addNewFfData().addNewCheckBox(); CTOnOff onOff = CTOnOff.Factory.newInstance(); onOff.setVal(STOnOff.ON); checkbox.setChecked(onOff);`

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. Thanks.