# Fill out form fields in a word 97-2007 document using POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, openxml, word-2003

I'm struggling how to read and fill out form fields (text, checkboxes) contained in a .dot document using Apache POI.

Sorry that I do not provide any code snippet but I have absolutely no idea how to **read and fill out** the fields.

Is there any code example available how to do so?

Comment: You mean the old binary `*.doc` format (Word 97-2003) right? I ask because Word 2007 uses Office Open XML (`*.docx`)  already. There should be solutions for Office Open XML (`*.docx`) using Apache POI. But for the old binary `*.doc` format I doubt that.

Comment: Yes I meant the old binary format. But if there is a solution for docx it may also be sufficient.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57589810/how-to-create-checkbox-and-input-text-fields-in-docx-document/57594794#57594794 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56409262/problem-with-processing-word-document-java/56412311#56412311

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments it's probably not possible with the old .dot format.

But there are existing code samples which handle form fields with the newer xml format:

1. [How to create checkbox and input text fields in docx document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57589810/how-to-create-checkbox-and-input-text-fields-in-docx-document/57594794#57594794)
2. [Problem with processing word document java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56409262/problem-with-processing-word-document-java/56412311#56412311)